# Log outgoing requests within a local dev env w/ php-fpm

Tags: php, fpm

Is there any option to log outgoing server requests within a local dev environment with php-fpm?

Comment: Nginx configuration is rather off-topic here, there's superuser.com for that. PHP/FPM may be on-topic, but it's unclear what an "outgoing server request" means. Who sends a request where?

Comment: A request initiated from the server side (via php) to an external endpoint.

Comment: Well, just use a logger (https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/, `composer` can automatically find implementations). Nginx is btw completely outside of this, because it never executes any PHP code directly but only by IPC to FPM.

Comment: BTW: You can [edit] your question to clarify it. Having half the info in comments isn't useful for others looking with similar problems.